# How to go through every word and not just the once for each word?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The function receives the text.

Currently, I pass the text in, and it checks for the words, telling me the start and end if it finds each word. But there are multiple 'Hello' in the text but only points out the first one same for the others. What if I wanted it to do it for every single match?

```
complexWordIdentification(text) {
  const complexWords = ['Hello', 'World', 'Complex Phrase'];
  const results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < complexWords.length; i++) {
    // the complex word we are checking in this iteration
    const complexWord = complexWords[i];
    const match = text.search(complexWord);
    if (match !== -1) {
      // the results object
      const result = {
        begin: match,
        end: match + complexWord.length,
        text: complexWord
      };
      const index = results.length;
      results[index] = result;
      console.log(results);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
complexWordIdentification('Hello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean mHello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean mHello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.')
```

The result currently:

`{begin: 0, end: 5, text: "Hello"}`

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I'm trying to find where 'else' Hello begins and ends because currently it finds them all but it only finds them once in the whole document. Even though there are 15 different Hellos in the document it only finds the first of each first.

Comment: Post the full relevant code. I only see one `Hello`. Also post an example result of what you are looking for.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Its a text file, filled with dummy text.

Comment: Then post the contents of it.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to recreate RegEx here, perhaps take a look at RegExp and Matches. Seems like it would do exactly what you need and be much less work.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn content of the text file "Hello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m Hello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean m Hello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. "

Comment: I need to know every single word that matches it and the start and end because I will later on need to highlight the word and add an annotation, its to help people understand text.

Comment: This is the result @GetOffMyLawn: 
{begin: 0, end: 5, text: "Hello"}
{begin: 6, end: 11, text: "Lorem"}
{begin: 12, end: 17, text: "ipsum"} But I want all the other hellos in the document too not just the first one of each word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a regular expression and [RegExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), you can retrieve the position of the matches.

Make sure you define your RegExp with the `'g'` operator to make it global so it keeps searching after the first match.

```js
function complexWordIdentification(text) {
  const complexWords = ['Hello', 'World', 'Complex Phrase'];
  const results = [];
  let match, regexp, result;

  for (let i = 0; i < complexWords.length; i++) {
    // the complex word we are checking in this iteration
    const complexWord = complexWords[i];
    regexp = new RegExp(complexWord, 'g');

    while ((match = regexp.exec(text)) !== null) {

      result = {
        begin: (regexp.lastIndex - complexWords[i].length),
        end: regexp.lastIndex,
        text: complexWord
      };
      results.push(result);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
const result = complexWordIdentification('Hello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean mHello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean mHello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.')

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If I was to change the `complexWords = [words];` which is pushed into the function just as the text got pushed in. The `this.words` has three different words, but why does it only do one word and not the rest? Many thanks

Comment: `complexWords = [words]` Why would you do that? You're pushing `words` into an array. So, `complexWords.length` is 1 instead of 3. It will break the logic and structure of the code.